# Регулярка для "элемента, который может как присутствовать, так и отсутствовать"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Дано:

```
var string = "SUBJECT  [CONST]  SOME TEXT HERE";
```

Разделителем между SUBJECT, [CONST] и SOME TEXT HERE выступает символ табуляции.

Нужно:

выпарсить SOME TEXT HERE.

Решение:

```
string.match(/.CONST.\t(\D*)/i)[1];
```

Но:

Случается так, что CONST не всегда обрамлен квадратными скобками и тогда точки будут лишними.
В доке написано, что

> ? Обозначает, что элемент может как присутствовать, так и отсутствовать. Например, /e?le?/ найдет 'el' в "angel" и 'le' в "angle."

Но при попытке заменить точки на знаки вопроса, получаем

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?CONST?\t(\D*)/: Nothing to repeat
```

Буду признателен за помощь, и, если не затруднит, объяснение, почему вариант со знаками вопроса не работает.

Comment: Так нужно не заменить точки, а поставить после них вопросы после них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ - еще раз внимательно перечитать доку. 
Знак вопроса, расположенный за символом наделяет его(символ) свойством быть игнорируемым при поиске выражения. 
Человекопонятный пример(условно): /СКРИПТ?/ найдет и СКРИП, и СКРИПТ

Мои благодарности за подсказку и, одновременно, извинения за глупость этого топика, Вам - Zelta.